# while and foreach loops in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, foreach, while-loop

I would like to save into a mySQL column the values taken from an external text file.

The text file is simply as follows:

```
line 1,
line 2,
line 3
```

As you can see, a comma on each line, followed by a linebreak.
Now, I need to update the database table (which counts 3 rows), with the text values (line 1, line 2 and line 3) in the column `text`.

So far, I have this:

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("docs/text");
$lines = explode(",\n", $text);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table'";
$qsql = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Error Query [".$sql."]");
while ($array = mysql_fetch_assoc($qsql)){
  foreach($lines as $line){
  mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `text`='".$line."'") or die(mysql_error());
  }
}
?>
```

The code above saves in all rows the same value (line 3).

Comment: OT: You need to stop using the mysql_* functions. They are dead and gone.

Comment: UPDATE modifies existing rows; **all rows** if no WHERE (or other limiting conditions) are present. INSERT adds new rows.

Comment: I am aware my syntax is not up-to-date.

Comment: UUeerdo, I've corrected my question. I actually need to update the table. Thanks.

Comment: @Alex so you need to append(?) every line in the text file to the `text` field every row in `table`?

Comment: So where exactly do you refer to the rows returned in the select (The `$array` in the outer loop)

Comment: How do you determine which row to be updated with which line?

Comment: @Progrock Exactly. I need to update column values in the same order as they are in the table (each row has a unique incremental id).

Comment: Well for a start you'll need to order by id ascending in your select.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to specify which row you want to [UPDATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html) (or [INSERT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert.html) if rows don't exist already). Here some quick and dirty  pseudo code:

```
for( $i=0; $i < count($lines); $i++ ){
  mysql_query("UPDATE `table` SET `text`='".$line[$i]."' where ID = ".$i) or die(mysql_error());
}
```

**Note:** It's recommended using `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql_*`- functions because of security implications.

Comment: This idea works, but line 1 from the text file is ignored. It starts updating from line 2.

Comment: Think it's because the Database ID starts by 1 and not 0. Have you tried `for( $i=1; $i <= count($lines); $i++ )` yet?

Comment: I have. That's weird.

Comment: Must be just a small mistake somewhere. Try to trace it down e.g. `var_dump` some values or start a debugging session